# Did the concept of "all for one and one for all" actually exist in France in the 17th century, or did it come later?

Tags: 19th-century, 17th-century, western-civilisation

The phrase ["all for one and one for all"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unus_pro_omnibus,_omnes_pro_uno) comes from the book "The Three Musketeers," which was set in the 1620s. But the book itself was published in 1844, which opens the possibility that a "later" (19th century) idea was injected into the plot of a novel that supposedly took place two centuries earlier.

This idea appears to be a key to Jean Jacque Rousseau's ["Social Contract"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Social_contract), (1762), which hypothesized that individuals should surrender their rights to the general will, and in turn receive the protection of the community. More to the point, it was the motto of the Swiss Confederation in the 19th century. It is therefore at least plausible that "The Three Musketeers" expounded on an idea popular at the time of its publication (19th century), rather than at the time of the novel's setting (17th century).

When do references to "all for one and one for all" start to appear in a French context, at least in concept, if not in actual quote? Was it actually in the 17th century or earlier, or was it after the 17th century?

Comment: According to your first link, Shakespeare used it in 1594 and the Bohemians in 1618 (Third Defenestration of Prague) so I'm a little confused about what it is you're looking for exactly.

Comment: I do not know if it qualifies, but Lope de Vega's [Fuenteovejuna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuenteovejuna), (written 1612-1614) tells the story of townspeople killing a royal official because of his abuses, and all the people of the town standing together to assume responsability when the King demands justice. The Spanish version of the WP states that it is based in an actual fact, with some possible additional inspiration, including 15th century *Gesta Hispaniense*. Does it match your criteria?

Comment: @LarsBosteen: Those were "non French" contexts. I'm looking for French contexts..

Comment: If I'm remembering the book correctly (it's been quite a while since I read it), the phrase has NOTHING whatsoever to do with a "social contract", or any greater society.  It is just an agreement between the three musketeers of the title.  That sort of agreement between members of small groups probably goes back to prehistory, and possibly predates language.

Comment: @jamesqf: Popular "books" like this often (not always) are a microcosm of the larger society. They usually aren't written in a vacuum.

Comment: @Tom Au: While that's true, it's also irrelevant.  As I said, that sort of agreement among small groups goes back to the dawn of history.  Indeed (and if I'm remembering the story correctly), the Three Musketeers are banded together for their own benefit, even when that's against the larger societies they act within.  So if anything, it expresses opposition to the so-called "social contract".

Comment: "*We must, indeed, all hang together or, most assuredly, we shall all hang separately.*" - Benjamin Franklin shortly after signing the Declaration of Independence. The sentiment is age old, as @jamesqf notes.